# Can't I replace using the capturing groups?

Tags: regex, perl

In the following script I am trying to keep the decimal part and the first 2 fractional parts and the third if it is greater than 0.
So 12.37500000000392 should be replaced to 12.375

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  

use strict;  
use warnings;  

my $price = 12.37500000000392;  
print "price = $price \n";  
$price =~ s/([0-9]+)(\.[1-9]{2}[1-9]?)\d*?/$1$2/;   

print "1 = $1 \n";  
print "2 = $2 \n";  
print "price = $price \n";
```

But it does not work.
It shows that `$1` is `12` and `$2` is `.375` but the price in the end is still printed as `12.37500000000392` in the last `print` statement

Comment: Is this an X/Y problem? Why don't you just say `$price = sprintf "%g",$price`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the ungreedy repetition at the end. Just use

```
$price =~ s/([0-9]+)(\.[1-9]{2}[1-9]?)\d*/$1$2/;
```

Since the `?` makes the `*` match as few repetitions as possible - and there are no further conditions at the end of the pattern that could make it fail - 0 repetitions of `\d` is the fewest possible, so the remaining digits are simply never matched, and hence not replaced.

Note that your pattern doesn't match at all if one of the first two digits is a zero. You probably wanted to use

```
$price =~ s/([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]{2}[1-9]?)\d*/$1$2/;
```

Also, if you don't need the integer and fractional parts later on, you could slightly simplify the entire thing like this:

```
$price =~ s/([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}[1-9]?)\d*/$1/;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with:

```
$price =~ s/\.\d{2}[1-9]?\K\d*//;
```

Comment: note that `\d` matches way more than only `[0-9]`, and I'd match at least one digit in front of the `\.` (as the current pattern uses `+`), but I don't even think it's a performance gain to leave that out. but +1 for `\K`